# How to use ehcache or JCS as a queue or streaming caching?

Tags: java, caching, queue, ehcache, jcs

I find that most of the features provided by ehCache are reasonably performing put and get by key..But I just want to use a caching to add and peek record as a queue(we need caching,much likes a buffer,because the data may be big..).How to use ehcache or JCS in this way?or any other suggested alternatives?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description it sounds like you would want to use JMS instead. Its supporting distributed transactions and provides publish/subscribe mechanisms.

Some of the JMS implementations:

- [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq)
- [OpenMQ](http://mq.java.net)
- [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org)